# Magento 2.2.2 Admin panel grids pushed to right

Tags: magento2, grid, admin-panel, magento2.2.2

At some point during developing my Magento 2 website, I flushed my cache and after a refresh, all the content on the admin panels are pushed to the right. I was working on a custom mass action under the orders tab, so I undid all my actions to the point before flushing the cache, but nothing seems to help. 
See following screen:

[image]

Comment: Try removing var folder and check. It may help. Or run static content deploy only for Magento/backend

Comment: Hm doesn't seem to work. Same results. I've checked the css file, and for some reason the following css is enabled "width: calc( (100%) * 0.75 - 30px )". When changing the 0.75 to 1, it works fine. But I'm working on a module which needs to be distributed, so I don't get why this suddenly is causing the width to alter and this should not happen on other installations of magento when using the module..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I couldn't figure out the problem. I reinstalled everything and now it works again. Probably some typo in some .xml file, I'm not sure.